# Apollo Client: difference between watched queries and active queries

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, react-apollo, apollo-client

Apollo client's documentation and tools refer to both `watched` queries and `active` queries. What is the difference between the 2? Are they interchangeable?

### Example of active query:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/#storing-local-state-in-reactive-variables

**Screenshot:**

[image]

### Example of watched query:

Inside Apollo Client Dev Tools:

[image]